# Stripe Payment Works only in my LocalHost but Does not work on Heroku server

Tags: javascript, node.js, web, heroku, stripe-payments

I'm learning web development and I was building this project but I have this problem Stripe Payment Works on LocalHost but Does not work on Heroku.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/UsMKp.png

and this is the current code 
https://github.com/unmalnickname/Ebook-Seller-App

and the Heroku site 
https://powerful-oasis-51375.herokuapp.com

Thank you for your time and help

Comment: *Does not work* - ok, in what way? Are there any errors in the browser developer console? What do you observe in the heroku site that differs from the working site (we can't see both, so we cant' compare)

Answer (score 0):

I accessed your site hosted in Heroku and tried to use the Stripe Checkout modal, it shows the error messages

"Invalid Publishable Keys"

Stripe Checkout requires you to pass the correct publishable keys to perform the checking.

So based on the error message, I am fairly sure that the Environment params [0] were not passed in properly in your Heroku Deployment. Either it is running in dev mode or the parameters are not passed in during node start.

Hope the above helps

[0] https://github.com/unmalnickname/Ebook-Seller-App/blob/master/config/keys.js#L1

Answer (score 0):

Could be that you have not added the stripe api key to the heroku Config Vars.